# SQL query to identify continuous events that satisfy a condition group by product id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data that looks as follows.

| timestamp | productid | measure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 00:01:00 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:02:00 | 1 | 6 |
| 2022-01-01 00:01:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 7 |
| 2022-01-01 00:01:00 | 3 | 9 |

The table records the telemetry of the product at 1-minute intervals.
The table has an incremental id which is not in any way uniquely identifiable. The primary index is a combination of productid and timestamp.

I want a query that can select productid and timestamp of the first row where the measure is between 4 and 5 for 10 continuous timestamps when the data is partitioned by productid and ordered by timestamp.

I tried creating a list of all measures that satisfy the condition and then seeing if they are continuous, but it is taking really long.

Comment: Please review [ask]. This question lacks necessary details. Please update the post with the table DDL (including indexes), the expected output, the query you tried, and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` on that query.

Comment: It is unclear from the question if the measurements are to be partitioned by `productid` or if the criteria is only met when the consecutive measurements are for the same `productid`.

Comment: @JohnH Sorry for the confusion. I updated the query with some more detail. Sadly, the query I used is in no way shape or form correct and I don't think it will be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Another gaps and islands problem. You say "over 10" so I will treat a run of any length as one unit:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case when measure between 4 and 5 then 1 else 0 end as qualified
    from T
), transitions as (
    select *,
        case when lag(qualified, 1, 0) 
            over (partition by productid order by timestamp) = 0 and qualified = 1
            then 1 else 0 end as flag
   from data
), groups as (
    select *,
        sum(flag) over (partition by productid order by timestamp) as grp
    from transitions
)
select productid, min(timestamp) as begintime, sum(qualified) as length
from groups
group by productid, grp;
having sum(qualified) > 10 -- or possibly you want>= 10?
order by productid, begintime;
```

The problem doesn't fundamentally change whether you need to partition by product or not. Just comment out those sections if not. The trick is to mark the spots where there's a transition and based on that the subsequent run of rows can be associated with a common and unique number (`grp`).